# Seesaw button bind WindowBuilder

Tags: clojure, windowbuilder, seesaw

Currently I'm using an application with a form designed in WindowBuilder. The form contains a button which I want to use in Clojure/seesaw. So my question is: how am I able to use the button defined in Java in Clojure?

Kind regards,
Mittchel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're following the [WindowBuilder example](https://github.com/daveray/seesaw/blob/develop/examples/window-builder/src/window_builder/core.clj), you can use `seesaw.core/select` to find the button and then use `seesaw.core/listen` as usual. For example, if you have a button named `"foo"` in your form and, *after* you've called the `identify` function:

```
(listen (select my-window-builder-form [:#foo]) 
  :action (fn [e] ... you're code ...))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! but I'm getting an error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No implementation of method: :id-of* of protocol: #'seesaw.selector/Selectable found for class: nil

In the following code: http://pastebin.com/inv3KKwN

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?